# pandas more efficient way to create dictionary object from csv to send as a post request

Tags: python, pandas

Sample data:

```
data = {'account': {0: 'ted',
1: 'ned',
2: 'bed',
3: 'fred',
4: 'med'},
'account_type': {0: 'Enterprise',
1: 'Enterprise',
2: 'Enterprise',
3: '',
4: 'Mid-Market'},
'rep': {0: 'bob', 1: 'sam', 2: 'sam', 3: 'bob', 4: 'tim'}, 
'id': {0: 5542, 1: 7118, 2: 5510, 3: 5872, 4: 5766}, 
'industry': {0: 'Electronics', 1: 'Retail', 2: '', 3: 'Books', 4: ''}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I created my desired output by doing the following:

```
properties = {'app_id':'12345','users':[]}
for i in df.index:
    _id = np.asscalar(np.int64(df.loc[i,'id']))
    properties['users'].append(
        {
            'id': _id,
            'properties': {
                'account': df.loc[i, 'account'],
                'rep': df.loc[i, 'rep'],
                'account_type': df.loc[i, 'account_type'],
                'industry': df.loc[i, 'industry']
            }
        }
    )
```

I feel like this is incredibly uninspiring and would like to know what would go into a more elegant solution that doesn't necessarily require a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more succinct solution using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`pandas.Series.to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
def build_users(row):
    properties = row.to_dict()
    del properties['id']
    return dict(id=row.id, properties=properties)

properties = {
    'app_id': '12345',
    'users': list(df.apply(build_users, axis=1)),
}
```

And using comprehensions:

```
properties = {
    'app_id': '12345',
    'users': [dict(
        id=i[0],
        properties=dict(
            account=i[1],
            rep=i[2],
            account_type=i[3],
            industry=i[4],
        )
    ) for i in zip(df.id, df.account, df.rep, df.account_type, df.industry)]
}
```

Comment: This is pretty neat! Can you think of anyway to do this zipping lists etc so you wouldn't have to loop?